# Apache2 mod_define not working

Tags: apache-2.2

I have used [mod_define](http://people.apache.org/~rjung/mod_define/) for Apache2 for a long time now in my Windows configuration. Now, I would like to move to Vagrant/Debian. However, I am facing difficulty reproducing the configuration in the virtual environment, which has Apache 2.2.22 installed.

The first problem I faced was being unable to compile the `.so` file: it kept telling me that the necessary libraries are not installed, and was refusing to install them. I don't remember how, but I managed eventually to compile. After this, I tried using it and it was not working, so I abandoned the idea for about a month.

Now, I'm back trying to make it work.
`mod_define` is installed, and is included in the output of `apache2 -M`, like so:

```
define_module (shared)
```

In my `/etc/apache2/mods-available/define.load` I have the following line:

```
LoadModule define_module      /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_define.so
```

So, it seems like it should work. However, when I try to start the server with `apache2ctl start` I get the following:

```
apache2: Syntax error on line 47 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/conf.d/gurudev.conf: Include directory '/etc/apache2/$ABC' not found
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

`/var/log/apache2/error.log` does not contain any new entries.
My `/etc/apache2/conf.d/gurudev.conf` file looks like this:

```
Define ABC "/var/www/.config/apache"
Include $ABC/*.conf
```

Looks like `$ABC` is not getting expanded to `/var/www/.config/apache`.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?
Or perhaps, my `mod_define.so` is broken? Maybe, somebody could send me theirs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just seems to be a limitation of `mod_define` and the `Include` directive for apache v2.2. You can used defined variables in many directives, but not in `Include`.

FYI, It works with apache v2.4's native `Define` directive